# Verify Member Identities for Community Self-Registration

Tags: apex, community, self-registration

I'm trying to test the new feature for the Salesforce Community: "Verify Member Identities for Community Self-Registration".

I want to create a Custom Verify Page and I'm reading the official docs:

[Verify Member Identities for Community Self-Registration](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_customize_login_passwordless_verify.htm&type=5)

[Create Your Own Verify Page for Community Sign-Ups](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_identity_login_custom_verify_pages.htm)

[UserManagement Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_UserManagement.htm)

[VerificationResult Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_VerificationResult.htm#topic-title)

I don't understand when they say:

> To generate your own Verify page for self-registration, create a Visualforce page and include the Apex methods System.UserManagement.initSelfRegistration and System.UserManagement.verifySelfRegistration.

Should I create an Apex Class extending some Interface? Should I add those two Apex methods in the current Handler using for the Configurable Sel-Reg Page?

It's not clear how I can implement this new feature.

Right now this is the configuration:

[image]

but I don't understand how I can trigger the new Verification Process using my Visualforce Page as long as I'm using the Configurable Self-Reg Page and the autogenerated Apex Handler and in this case the owner of the Verification Process is the platform.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried looking at the docs and couldn't really find as how you can implement that VF page or where to write the snippet as mentioned in the release docs. You may like to reach out to Salesforce support on this. And if you get a response back, do add that as an answer so that we know how to do this.

Comment: Hi, just reaching out to understand this feature if anyone was able to figure out the documentation for this?